# Find the number of different teams that can be selected if the team contains all $4$ women?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A team of $6$ people is to be selected from $8$ men and $4$ women. Find the number of different teams that can be selected if:

**(i)** there are no restrictions, (I solved this using ${n\choose r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ the answer is $924$.)

**(ii)** the team contains all $4$ women.

How do i solve part **(ii)**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four out of $6$ positions are filled by the four women, leaving an all-men pool of eight. Since the women have been assigned to four of the six positions, there are only $2$ remaining spots to fill, out of $8$ men. $$\binom{8}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!! You're amazing man!!

Comment: @Kiara she's a woman.

Comment: @mathh lol...i call both man and woman by man....;)

Answer (score 0):

Just select the remaining two men from 8.